# Java Seperate method to Convert double input to 2 decimal place

Tags: java

I have read many posts in this forum on converting user input to 2 decimal place.

However, I am required to write a method on its own and only be responsible for converting user input to 2 decimal places.

I am currently meeting an error of not being able to convert String to double when doing the decimal conversion.

Below is my current code.

```
public class LabQuestion
{

static double twoDecimalPlace (double usrInput){
    DecimalFormat twoDpFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    usrInput=twoDpFormat.format(usrInput);
    return usrInput;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{  

    System.out.print("Enter a number on a line: ");        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double d = input.nextDouble();

    twoDecimalPlace("Current input ",d);
}
}
```

How may I be able to create a method that allows converting to 2 decimal place of a double input from user? Thank you.

Comment: You use a NumberFormat object such as a DecimalFormat object to convert a String to a number, which is called "parsing" the String or a number to a String, which is called "formatting" the number, and so you will need to decide which it is you would like to do with this method.

Comment: I would like to have a check on the public on the user input to verify that the String input is a number, and a separate method to convert the verified input (String input which is verified as a number input) to 2 decimal place. May I know if I am on the correct track? I am still catching up with my foundation on programming after National Service. Will appreciate any help given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a NumberFormat object such as a DecimalFormat object to convert a String to a number, which is called "parsing" the String or a number to a String, which is called "formatting" the number, and so you will need to decide which it is you would like to do with this method. It sounds like you want to change the display of the number to show a String representation with 2 decimal places, and so I think that your output should be a String. For example:

---

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberFormater {
   static DecimalFormat twoDpFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

   static String twoDecimalPlace(double usrInput) {
      String output = twoDpFormat.format(usrInput);
      return output;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.print("Enter a number on a line: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      double d = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Output: " + twoDecimalPlace(d));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried implementing it. It does it's job in converting input that has more than 2 decimal points. But I would like the user to display 2 decimal points even when it is a whole number, e.g. 5.00. And may i know how do I catch when user doesn't input an integer? Thank you very much

Comment: @RUiHAO: change to `new DecimalFormat("#0.00");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public Double formatDouble(Number number){
    return Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.3f", "" + number));  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am required to use a separate method to implement the conversion. It is an extra step, but that's what I'm required, sadly :(

Comment: Are you hard getting it inside another function ?

Comment: Yes, a new function to carry out the conversion is a must. Appreciate any help. Thank you!